# x in range function for float in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to test whether a voltage is within the allowed range:

```
SET_VOLTAGE = 13
ERROR_VOLTAGE = 0.5
Vbatt = 12.86
if Vbatt in range ((SET_VOLTAGE-ERROR_VOLTAGE),(SET_VOLTAGE+1+ERROR_VOLTAGE)):
    print'True - Value in range'
else:
     print'False - Value out of range'
```

This code always prints the `False` value.  Why?  And what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

#### `range` returns a *list of values*, and `in` checks for *membership*

It requires integer arguments (I get a `TypeError` from your code).

What you are looking for is a floating point "between" comparison.

That is written

```
if -ERROR_VOLTAGE <= Vbatt-SET_VOLTAGE <= ERROR_VOLTAGE:
```

or perhaps

```
if abs(Vbatt-SET_VOLTAGE) <= ERROR_VOLTAGE:
```